# add validation inside an Ionic creator page

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have obtained a Ionic creator project with this hierarchy:

```
-index.html
-templates (directory)
    --signup.html
    --signin.html
-lib (directory)
-css (directory)
-js (directory)
```

so... how can I add a simple validation to signup.html page? This is ALL the signup.html code, how can I modify it? I want all fields to be mandatory.

```
<ion-view title="Registrazione" id="page2" style="background-color: rgb(181, 210, 253);">

    <ion-content padding="true" scroll="false" class="has-header">

        <form id="registrazione-form3" name="formSignup" class="list" method="POST" action="SignupServlet" novalidate>
            <ion-list id="registrazione-list1">
                <label class="item item-input" id="registrazione-input5">
                    <span class="input-label">Nome:</span>
                    <input placeholder="" type="text" name="nome" >
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input" id="registrazione-input6">
                    <span class="input-label">Cognome:</span>
                    <input placeholder="" type="text" name="cognome" >
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input" id="registrazione-input7">
                    <span class="input-label">Email:</span>
                    <input placeholder="" type="email" name="email" >
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input" id="user">
                    <span class="input-label">Username:</span>
                    <input placeholder="" type="text" name="username" >
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input" id="registrazione-input10">
                    <span class="input-label">Password:</span>
                    <input placeholder="" type="text" name="password" >
                </label>
            </ion-list>


            <button id="registrazione-button2" class="button button-      positive button-block" >Registrati</button>
        </form>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ngMessages'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('signin', {
      url: '/sign-in',
      templateUrl: 'templates/sign-in.html',
      controller: 'SignInCtrl'
    })
    .state('forgotpassword', {
      url: '/forgot-password',
      templateUrl: 'templates/forgot-password.html'
    })
    .state('tabs', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts', {
      url: '/facts',
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/facts.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts2', {
      url: '/facts2',
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/facts2.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: '/about',
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/about.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: '/navstack',
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/nav-stack.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.contact', {
      url: '/contact',
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/contact.html'
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/sign-in');

})

.controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.user = {
    username: '',
    password : ''
  };
  $scope.signIn = function(form) {
    console.log(form);
    if(form.$valid) {
    console.log('Sign-In', $scope.user.username);
    $state.go('tabs.home');
    }
  };
  
})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
});
```

```css
label.item.has-error {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

label.item.has-error-lr {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

label.item.valid-lr {
  border-left: 2px solid green;
  border-right: 2px solid green;
}

.form-errors {
  margin: 5px 0
}

.form-error {
  padding: 2px 0 2px 16px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Sign-in, Then Tabs Example</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <script id="templates/form-errors.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">This field is required.</div>
      <div class="form-error" ng-message="minlength">This field is must be at least 5 characters.</div>
      <div class="form-error" ng-message="maxlength">This field is must be less than 50 characters</div>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/sign-in.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Sign-In">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <form name="signinForm" novalidate="" ng-submit="signIn(signinForm)">

            <div class="list">
              <label class="item item-input" 
                     ng-class="{ 'has-error' : signinForm.username.$invalid}">
                <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                <input type="text"
                       name="username"
                       ng-model="user.username" 
                       ng-minlength="5" 
                       ng-maxlength="10" 
                       required>
              </label>

              <div class="form-errors" ng-messages="signinForm.username.$error" ng-messages-include="templates/form-errors.html">
                <div class="form-error" ng-message="maxlength">This field is must be less than 10 characters</div>
              </div>

              <label class="item item-input" 
                     ng-class="{ 'has-error-lr' : signinForm.password.$invalid  && signinForm.$submitted, 'valid-lr' : signinForm.password.$valid  && signinForm.$submitted}">
                <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                <input type="password"
                       name="password"
                       ng-model="user.password" 
                       ng-minlength="5" 
                       ng-maxlength="25"
                       required>
              </label>
              <div class="form-errors" 
                   ng-show="signinForm.password.$error && signinForm.$submitted"
                   ng-messages="signinForm.password.$error"
                   ng-messages-include="templates/form-errors.html">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="padding">
              <button class="button button-block button-positive">
                Sign-In
              </button>
              <p class="text-center">
                <a href="#/forgot-password">Forgot password</a>
              </p>
            </div>

          </form>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/forgot-password.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Forgot Password">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p>
            Yeah this is just a demo showing how views can be shown without tabs, then you can navigate
            to views within tabs. Additionally, only one set of tabs needs to be written for all of the different views that should go inside the tabs. (Compared to written the same tab links in the footer of every view that's in a tab.)
          </p>
          <p>
            There's no username/password, just click
            the Sign-In button back a the sign-in view.
          </p>
          <p>
            Return to <a href="#/sign-in">Sign-In</a>.
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view>
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

          <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
            <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
          </ion-tab>

          <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios7-information" href="#/tab/about">
            <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
          </ion-tab>

          <ion-tab title="Sign-Out" icon="ion-log-out" href="#/sign-in">
          </ion-tab>

        </ion-tabs>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p>Example of Ionic tabs. Navigate to each tab, and
            navigate to child views of each tab and notice how
            each tab has its own navigation history.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Facts">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
          <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
          <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
          <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
          <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script> 

    <script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Also Factual">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
          <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
          <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
          <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
          <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
          <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="About">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
          <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
          <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p><img src="https://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, but where do I insert each piece of this code? Could you be more detailed?

Comment: first peace of code you need to add in your app.js..the second one is css file which you can create your custom.css and include path for this file into index,html file and last one is html page like you can use as your signup.html and remove extra code which is not necessary for you..I hope this might helps you..!!